# Renamed network interfaces

Tags: networking, networkcard, interface

A recent update on my Mint system caused the `eth1` to end up being renamed as `eth3` and therefore breaking all my firewall & forwarding rules. How does this happen? How can I enforce  the network interfaces names to remain consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are usually named via udev. You can find the detailed rules for this in a file like:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

If udev finds a "known" interface it uses the name configured there. If udev finds a new interface it will give it a new name and add a corresponding rule there.

You can change that file and give you interfaces a meaningful name.

Comment: It's weird that an update would mess with the `udev` rules, though. After all, the `udev` rules for persistent network interfaces involve physical addresses.

Comment: Yes, it is strange. But maybe a look at those rules will help understand what happened.